# Typing an Array in TypeScript when pushing data

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am typing an array in Typescript where I am pushing some objects, but I cant find the right way to do it.

Here is the code:

```
interface IUsersItem {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  email: string;
}

interface ISeeds {
  [key: string]: IUsersItem[];
}

const seeds: ISeeds = {
  Users: [
    {
      name: "aaa",
      surname: "bbb",
      email: "aaa.bbb@example.com"
    },
    {
      name: "ccc",
      surname: "ddd",
      email: "ccc.ddd@example.com"
    }
  ]
};

interface IModelsItem {
  name: string;
  someMethod: string;
}
interface IModels {
  [key: string]: IModelsItem;
}

const models = {
  Users: {
    name: "Users",
    someMethod: "xxx"
  }
};

let dataToSeed = [];
Object.keys(seeds).forEach((item) => {
  dataToSeed.push({
    data: seeds[item],
    model: models[item]
  });
});
```

Here is the example in the TypeScript playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Try providing type to your `models` i.e. `const models: IModels`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type is not provided to `models`, so it is automatically inferred to be as follows, which lacks `[key: string]`.

```
{
  User: {
    name: string;
    someMethod: string;
  };
}
```

You can add a type to `models` as follows.

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  someMethod: string;
}

const models: { [key: string]: IUser } = {
  Users: {
    name: "Users",
    someMethod: "xxx"
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

The error was while pushing into the dataToSeed array due model. Provide type to models constant as any.

const models: any = {
  Users: {
    name: "Users",
    someMethod: "xxx"
  }
};

Comment: Explicitly annotating things as any is not a good idea. It completely bypasses any type checks.